# TypeScript Types for Resolvers GraphQL yoga (use prisma2 on context)

Tags: typescript, types, graphql, prisma, codegen

Sry about my English

So, i need create Types for resolvers on GraphQL yoga. I create this with graphql-codegen, but it works weirdly. And he do not currently create types context for Prisma2.

codegen.yml

```
schema: ./src/schema.graphql
generates:
  ./src/resolvers/resolvers-types.ts:
    plugins:
      - typescript
      - typescript-resolvers
config:
  contextType: './context#Context'
```

context.ts

```
import {PrismaClient} from '@prisma/client'

export type Context = { prisma:PrismaClient }
```

resolvers.ts

```
import {IResolvers, Mutation} from './resolvers-types'

interface StringIndexSignatureInterface {
    [index: string]: any
}

type StringIndexed<T> = T & StringIndexSignatureInterface

const resolvers: StringIndexed<IResolvers> = {
Query: {
        users: (parent, args, ctx, info) => {
            return ctx.prisma.user.findMany
        }
    }
};
```

he throw error about type incompatibility

Without StringIndexed he don't work

Plz tell me how i can do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find solution
I add to codegen.yml contextType

codegen.yml

```
generates:
  ./src/resolvers/resolvers-types/resolvers-types.ts:
    plugins:
      - typescript
      - typescript-resolvers
      
config:
  contextType: './context#Context'
  enumsAsTypes: true
```

context.ts

```
import {PrismaClient} from '@prisma/client'

export type Context = { prisma:PrismaClient}
```